# Explode does not work with multilpe commas inside the string

Tags: php, function, explode

I try to find the answer here and in Google but no luck!

Why it does not work when I try to explode the string?

```
$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";

$Text_Array = explode(",",$Text);

$Text_Array = array_filter($Text_Array);

print_r($Text_Array);
```

I would like to have all my tags divide by ONE comma and remove any space and duplicate tags.

**I would like this result:**

"brazil,banks,home,uk,test,financial times,ipad,Two words";

Please, can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: The use str_replace() before exploding; or use str_getcsv()

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens and what exactly do you expect instead?

Comment: what is expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `remove any space and duplicate tags` then you need to also add `array_unique` with `array_filter`

```
$textAray = array_unique(array_filter($textAray));
```

**Note** .. Please this would not remove the `.` in the result .. here is a better way to filter your results

```
$text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";
$textArray = array_unique(preg_split("/[,.]+/", $text));
$textArray = array_filter($textArray);
echo implode(",", $textArray);
```

Output

```
brazil,banks,home,uk,test,financial times,ipad,Two words
```

Comment: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` would spare you having to call `array_filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is array_unique function:

```
$Text_Array = array_unique($Text_Array);
```

So your code becomes:

```
$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";

$Text_Array = explode(",",$Text);

$Text_Array = array_filter($Text_Array);

$Text_Array = array_unique($Text_Array);\

print_r($Text_Array);
```

and you will then get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace multiple continuous commas by a single comma before you explode the string

```
$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";

$Text = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $Text);
$Text_Array = explode(",",$Text);

print_r($Text_Array);
```

Note that you will still have one element in your array containing a dot, and the last element of the array will be empty if your string ends with a comma.

Comment: Not `preg_replace()` then `explode()` -- use `preg_split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need such kind of code

```
$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";

$str = substr(preg_replace('/(.+?)[,]+/', '$1,', $Text),0,strlen($str)-1);
$arr = array_unique(explode(',', $str));
print_r($arr);
```

1. You need to replace ,, or more with one , I've done it with preg_replace
2. Remove last , from the string
3. Explode by ,
4. Remove duplicates by array_unique()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";
$Text = str_replace('.','',implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $Text))));
$Text_Array = explode(",",$Text);

$Text_Array = array_filter($Text_Array);

print_r($Text_Array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution given by these people you can try this to print values as u wanted:-

```
foreach($Text_Array as $textval)
{
echo $textval . ",";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u may try this

```
<?php

$Text = "brazil,banks,home,,uk,,,,test,financial times,.,ipad,,banks,,Two words,,";

$Text=str_replace(array(",,",",,,,",",.,",",,"),',',$Text);

$Text_Array = explode(",",$Text);

$Text_Array = array_filter($Text_Array);

print_r($Text_Array);
//output :: Array ( [0] => brazil [1] => banks [2] => home [3] => uk [4] => test [5] => financial times [6] => ipad [7] => banks [8] => Two words )
?>
```

Comment: this isnt the most efficient way to do this, your str_replace would have to be editted if another comma is added in the string. look at a regex replace for a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove all unncessary commata in your example by replacing ',,' with ',' until no more ',,' exists.

```
while ( strstr($Text,',,') !== false ) {
    $Text = str_replace($Text,',,',',');
}
```

Used functions:

- [strstr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php)
- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)